# Save new order of list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I try to make it possible to save my listview's new order to cookies so user can sort list how they want. And next time when they open my page list is same order than it was when they leave the page. Is this possible?

I use jQuery Mobile and I make list sortable this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').taphold(function() {
      // the clicked LI
      var clicked = $(this);

      // all the LIs above the clicked one
      var previousAll = clicked.prevAll();

      // only proceed if it's not already on top (no previous siblings)
      if(previousAll.length > 0) {
        // top LI
        var top = $(previousAll[previousAll.length - 1]);

        // immediately previous LI
        var previous = $(previousAll[0]);

        // how far up do we need to move the clicked LI?
        var moveUp = clicked.attr('offsetTop') - top.attr('offsetTop');

        // how far down do we need to move the previous siblings?
        var moveDown = (clicked.offset().top + clicked.outerHeight()) - (previous.offset().top + previous.outerHeight());

        // let's move stuff
        clicked.css('position', 'relative');
        previousAll.css('position', 'relative');
        clicked.animate({'top': -moveUp});
        previousAll.animate({'top': moveDown}, {complete: function() {
          // rearrange the DOM and restore positioning when we're done moving
          clicked.parent().prepend(clicked);
          clicked.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
          previousAll.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0}); 
        }});
      }
    });
  });
```

When user tap and hold list item that item move to the top of list.

**+ My page have to be able to use offline too.**

***UPDATE:***

How do I get links to the new list?
Now I have like this:

**JS**

```
$('#home').live('pageinit', function(event) {
    // Check if we have saved the list order
    getListOrder();

    $('li').taphold(function() {
        // the clicked LI
        var clicked = $(this);

        // all the LIs above the clicked one
        var previousAll = clicked.prevAll();

        // only proceed if it's not already on top (no previous siblings)
        if (previousAll.length > 0) {
            // top LI
            var top = $(previousAll[previousAll.length - 1]);

            // immediately previous LI
            var previous = $(previousAll[0]);

            // how far up do we need to move the clicked LI?
            var moveUp = clicked.attr('offsetTop') - top.attr('offsetTop');

            // how far down do we need to move the previous siblings?
            var moveDown = (clicked.offset().top + clicked.outerHeight()) - (previous.offset().top + previous.outerHeight());

            // let's move stuff
            clicked.css('position', 'relative');
            previousAll.css('position', 'relative');
            clicked.animate({
                'top': -moveUp
            });
            previousAll.animate({
                'top': moveDown
            }, {
                complete: function() {
                    // rearrange the DOM and restore positioning when we're done moving
                    clicked.parent().prepend(clicked);
                    clicked.css({
                        'position': 'static',
                        'top': 0
                    });
                    previousAll.css({
                        'position': 'static',
                        'top': 0
                    });
                    saveListOrder();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#resetLO').click(function() {
        resetListOrder();
    });

    $('#clearLS').click(function() {
        clearLocalStorage();
    });
});

function saveListOrder() {
    var $items = $('#theList li');

    $items.each(function(i) {
        //alert('Order:' +$(this).attr('rel')+' I: '+i); // This is your rel value
        // save the index and the value
        localStorage.setItem(i, $(this).attr('rel'));
    });
}

function getListOrder() {
    var list   = $("#theList");
    var $items = $('#theList li');
    var item;

    // check for localStorage
    if(localStorage.getItem(0) == null) {
        return; // use default list order
    }        

    // remove the previous list
    list.empty();

    $items.each(function(i) {
        item = localStorage.getItem(i);

        // create new list order
        list.append('<li rel="'+item+'"><a href="#">List Item #'+item+'</a></li>');
    });
    list.listview('refresh');    
}

function resetListOrder() {
    var list   = $("#theList");
    var $items = $('#theList li');
    var next;

    // remove the previous list
    list.empty();

    $items.each(function(i) {
        next = i + 1;
        list.append('<li rel="'+next+'"><a href="#">List Item #'+next+'</a></li>');
    });  
    list.listview('refresh');     
}

function clearLocalStorage() {
    // remove  all saved data
    localStorage.clear();     
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="theList">
            <li rel="1"><a href="http://www.example1.com">List Item #1</a></li>
            <li rel="2"><a href="http://www.example2.com">List Item #2</a></li>
            <li rel="3"><a href="http://www.example3.com">List Item #3</a></li>
            <li rel="4"><a href="http://www.example4.com">List Item #4</a></li>
            <li rel="5"><a href="http://www.example5.com">List Item #5</a></li>
            <li rel="6"><a href="http://www.example6.com">List Item #6</a></li>
            <li rel="7"><a href="http://www.example7.com">List Item #7</a></li>
            <li rel="8"><a href="http://www.example8.com">List Item #8</a></li>
            <li rel="9"><a href="http://www.example9.com">List Item #9</a></li>
            <li rel="10"><a href="http://www.example10.com">List Item #10</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="resetLO">Reset List Order</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="clearLS">Clear Local Storage</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I reorder list and save it, then it change the link to the "#".

Example: I move Item3 to the top of the list so every items' link change http://www.example3.com -> #

So I guess it clear old list and make whole list again. So I guess I have to change this line, but I don't know how. `list.append('<li rel="'+item+'"><a href="#">List Item #'+item+'</a></li>');`

Comment: I did this once and what I ended up doing was writing the contents and order of the list to a file every time it changed, and then loading that file on page load. Would that work for you? Also, I'm pretty sure there's a jQuery plugin for that, so you don't have to do it with CSS...

Comment: @Colleen: Do you have any examples to give me? I'm new in jQuery/HTML coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTML5 I would look at localStorage

- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp
- http://sixrevisions.com/html/introduction-web-storage/

UPDATE:

Here is an example using Local Storage

- http://jsfiddle.net/TWMEq/
- http://jsfiddle.net/TWMEq/1/ (Reload List Order)

JS

```
$('#home').live('pageinit', function(event) {
    // Check if we have saved the list order
    getListOrder();

    $('li').taphold(function() {
        // the clicked LI
        var clicked = $(this);

        // all the LIs above the clicked one
        var previousAll = clicked.prevAll();

        // only proceed if it's not already on top (no previous siblings)
        if (previousAll.length > 0) {
            // top LI
            var top = $(previousAll[previousAll.length - 1]);

            // immediately previous LI
            var previous = $(previousAll[0]);

            // how far up do we need to move the clicked LI?
            var moveUp = clicked.attr('offsetTop') - top.attr('offsetTop');

            // how far down do we need to move the previous siblings?
            var moveDown = (clicked.offset().top + clicked.outerHeight()) - (previous.offset().top + previous.outerHeight());

            // let's move stuff
            clicked.css('position', 'relative');
            previousAll.css('position', 'relative');
            clicked.animate({
                'top': -moveUp
            });
            previousAll.animate({
                'top': moveDown
            }, {
                complete: function() {
                    // rearrange the DOM and restore positioning when we're done moving
                    clicked.parent().prepend(clicked);
                    clicked.css({
                        'position': 'static',
                        'top': 0
                    });
                    previousAll.css({
                        'position': 'static',
                        'top': 0
                    });
                    saveListOrder();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#resetLO').click(function() {
        resetListOrder();
    });

    $('#clearLS').click(function() {
        clearLocalStorage();
    });
});

function saveListOrder() {
    var $items = $('#theList li');

    $items.each(function(i) {
        //alert('Order:' +$(this).attr('rel')+' I: '+i); // This is your rel value
        // save the index and the value
        localStorage.setItem(i, $(this).attr('rel'));
    });
}

function getListOrder() {
    var list   = $("#theList");
    var $items = $('#theList li');
    var item;

    // check for localStorage
    if(localStorage.getItem(0) == null) {
        return; // use default list order
    }        

    // remove the previous list
    list.empty();

    $items.each(function(i) {
        item = localStorage.getItem(i);

        // create new list order
        list.append('<li rel="'+item+'"><a href="#">List Item #'+item+'</a></li>');
    });
    list.listview('refresh');    
}

function resetListOrder() {
    var list   = $("#theList");
    var $items = $('#theList li');
    var next;

    // remove the previous list
    list.empty();

    $items.each(function(i) {
        next = i + 1;
        list.append('<li rel="'+next+'"><a href="#">List Item #'+next+'</a></li>');
    });  
    list.listview('refresh');     
}

function clearLocalStorage() {
    // remove  all saved data
    localStorage.clear();     
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="theList">
            <li rel="1"><a href="#">List Item #1</a></li>
            <li rel="2"><a href="#">List Item #2</a></li>
            <li rel="3"><a href="#">List Item #3</a></li>
            <li rel="4"><a href="#">List Item #4</a></li>
            <li rel="5"><a href="#">List Item #5</a></li>
            <li rel="6"><a href="#">List Item #6</a></li>
            <li rel="7"><a href="#">List Item #7</a></li>
            <li rel="8"><a href="#">List Item #8</a></li>
            <li rel="9"><a href="#">List Item #9</a></li>
            <li rel="10"><a href="#">List Item #10</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="resetLO">Reset List Order</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="clearLS">Clear Local Storage</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: I don't know how to use localStorage, because I have about 10 items already in list and if user sort them and save to the localStorage, so I have to be able to somehow to just update that localStorage. Right? And how :D

Comment: Phill Pafford: One more question: How do I can pass link (href="http://example.com") to the new ordered list? Every item have different link. Now it only make that new ordered list have link "#". :)

Comment: can you give a little  more detail?

Comment: Phill Pafford: see my update. Hope you understand what I trying to do. :)

Comment: Phill Pafford: Nope because those links are different. That www.example.com was only in this example. I have to use like this: 1st item: google.com, second item: yahoo.com, third item: bing.com etc..

Comment: just replace the example.com with the links you need

Comment: Phill Pafford: Like what do you mean? Like I make this line 3 times with different link? `list.append('<li rel="'+item+'"><a href="http://www.example'+item+'.com">List Item #'+item+'</a></li>'); Or I just skip that "http://www.examlple" and leave only '+item+?

Answer (score 0):

without dumping a 2 entire files on you, some relevant excerpts from the page I mentioned:

in my JS file:

```
//fetches the list and calls show list to show the contents
function getList(){
    //alert("in getList");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"todolist.php",
        success: function(responseText){showList(responseText)},
        error: ajaxFailure
    });
}
//keeps track of the new order when the user drags to reorder
function updateOrder(){
    var listitems=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var liststring="";
    for(var i=0; i<listitems.length; i++){
        liststring=liststring+"\n"+listitems[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"todolist.php",
        success: getList,
        error: ajaxFailure,
        type: "post",
        data: {action: "set", items: liststring}
    });
}
```

todolist.php contains (among other content):

```
    } else {
    $items=$_REQUEST["items"];
        if($action=="set"){
            file_put_contents("todolist.txt", $items);
        } else { //add an item
            print($items);
            file_put_contents("todolist.txt", "\n".$items, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
} else {
    //print the current file
    if(file_exists("todolist.txt")){
        $contents=file_get_contents("todolist.txt");
        if($contents!=""){
            $contents=trim($contents);
            print($contents);
        }
    } 
}
```

and I just called .sortable() on the list to make it dragable/dropable/sortable, if I remember correctly.

However, the php method doesn't address your issue of being usable offline (if you mean that you want to retain full functionality), because of course an ajax request requires it to be online. But I'm not sure how much functionality you need, so this may work for you.